# Load an image in flash/actionscript from a different origin domain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, amazon-s3, cross-domain

I'm a complete noob when it comes to flash coding.

I have a flash swf file that I'm loading from an S3 assets bucket.  Inside the flash swf it *should* be displaying a "Browse" button, images also courtesy of the same bucket.  This works fine when I host the images and swf file from the same domain that the site is on, but not when loaded from S3.

I have added a `crossdomain.xml` file to the assets bucket as follows (I'm trying with '*' to start just to get it working, and will narrow it down to my actual host when it appears to be doing anything):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I also have a cross-origin resource sharing configuration in the bucket so that the fonts will correctly load for our stylesheets (This is working).

What am I doing wrong to make the button images load in the actionscript?  Do I need to modify the actionscript code itself?  The code is located here (public library anyone can use, not authored by me): [s3-swf-upload-plugin](https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin/tree/master/flex_src/src)

You can see [here](https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin/blob/master/flex_src/src/S3Uploader.as#L59) that it is instantiating a new `browseButton` defined [here](https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin/blob/master/flex_src/src/com/nathancolgate/s3_swf_upload/BrowseButton.as).  Like I said I'm not totally familiar with actionscript but believe I could fumble through it if someone could show me what's going wrong :)  What's a good way to get actual error reporting?  Firebug in Firefox and Chrome's console don't have any kind of messages from Flash about errors going on.

**EDIT:**

There were some quirkinesses going on in the setting up of the flash object and setting the paths for the button images.  I updated `BrowseButton.as` to do this:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/crossdomain.xml");
```

I placed this before any of the `URLRequest` calls in the `BrowseButton()` function.  However it's still not displaying the images :(  I also hardcoded the values in the URLRequest to be things like:

```
upLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/assets/s3_up_button.gif"));
```

but nothing seems to happen.  When I set it to `/assets/s3_up_button.gif` to pull from the local file then it works fine.  What am I doing wrong!  How can I get error messages displaying from the flash video?  :\  I compiled with `<debug>true</debug>` but I'm not sure how to get actual exception messages.

Comment: Try Catching the errors thrown, to debug better : http://www.designscripting.com/2011/02/try-catch-statement-in-actionscript-flash-try-catch-exception-handling-as3/

Comment: If you install the flash debugger player (http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) you can configure it to log traces (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/configure-debugger-version-flash-player.html), which may help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: @wvxvw - surely `http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/crossdomain.xml` will cover `"http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/assets/s3_up_button.gif"` - the `assets/` path is under the `http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/` root?

Answer (score 1):

Check what sandbox your swf is in:

> The Security.sandboxType property
>
> An author of a SWF file can use the read-only static
>   Security.sandboxType property to determine the type of sandbox to
>   which Flash Player has assigned the SWF file. The Security class
>   includes constants that represent possible values of the
>   Security.sandboxType property, as follows:

```
Security.REMOTE--The SWF file is from an Internet URL, and operates under domain-based sandbox rules.
Security.LOCAL_WITH_FILE--The SWF file is a local file, but it has not been trusted by the user and was not published with a networking designation. The SWF file can read from local data sources but cannot communicate with the Internet.
Security.LOCAL_WITH_NETWORK--The SWF file is a local file and has not been trusted by the user, but it was published with a networking designation. The SWF can communicate with the Internet but cannot read from local data sources.
Security.LOCAL_TRUSTED--The SWF file is a local file and has been trusted by the user, using either the Settings Manager or a Flash Player trust configuration file. The SWF file can both read from local data sources and communicate with the Internet.
```

You probably want `Security.LOCAL_WITH_NETWORK`, although `Security.LOCAL_TRUSTED` will also work.

An explanation, along with details of how to set the sandbox in Flex, is here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05B_Security_04.html

If you're working in the Flash IDE, it should just be part of the publish settings.